# rxjs 6 observable<any> to observable<any[]>

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire, rxjs6

I use angular/fire valueChanges() get a document

```
const countries: Observable<any> = this.AngularFireStorage
      .doc('country/country')
      .valueChanges()
```

if add pipe(tap(x => console.log(x)). It will log

```
{ jp: {id: jp}, us: {id: us}}
```

what I want is add pipe(tap(x => console.log(x)) and get

```
{id: jp}
{id: us}
```

How to convert countries: Observable<any> to countries: Observable<any[]>

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `pipe(tap(x => console.log(x))`

**Write:**

```
pipe(tap(x =>
    const result = [];
    Object.keys(x).forEach(key => result.push(x[key]));
    console.log(result);
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to turn an object's values into an array. You can use any of the three common higher-order operators (`switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap`) to turn that array into a stream of values.

Here's how that might look:

```ts
const countries: Observable<any> = this.AngularFireStorage
  .doc('country/country').valueChanges().pipe(
    concatMap(Object.values),
    tap(console.log)
  )
```